# Can't insert data to MySQL remote server via PHP script from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I'm trying to insert data into two database tables from Android via a PHP script. I managed to load something from database, so permissions and database seem ok, but this code fails even though I think I have followed exactly what is presented in some examples.

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_date` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` enum('Waiting', 'Accepted', 'Production','Transport', 'Finalised', 'Canceled') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Waiting',
  `user_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `pizza_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pizza_size` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `income` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `pizza_id` (`pizza_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sales_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`login`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `sales_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pizza_id`) REFERENCES `pizzas` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `deliveries` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   //sale id actually
  `adress` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `client_name` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  UNIQUE KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `delivery_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `sales` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is the .php script that I wrote to insert data to these tables:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("www.db4free.net","user","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pizzaID = $_POST['pizzaID'];
$pizzaSize = $_POST['pizzaSize'];
$income = $_POST['income'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$clientName = $_POST['clientName'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

$time = time();                 //I want to pass current timestamp
$SQLInsertSale = "INSERT INTO sales VALUES(Null, '{$time}', 'Waiting', '{$user}', '{$pizzaID}', '{$pizzaSize}', '{$income}');";
$someResult = mysql_query($SQLInsertSale);

$SQLLastID = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id;";
$result = mysql_query($SQLLastID);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$lastID = $row['id'];


$SQLInsertDelivery = "INSERT INTO deliveries VALUES('{$lastID}', '{$address}', '{$clientName}', '{$telephone}', 0.0);";
$someResult = mysql_query($SQLInsertDelivery);

mysql_close();
?>
```

and finally this is the code I run on android (I call this method inside `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask`):

```
public static void sendData(String user, int pizzaID, int pizzaSize,  double income,
                         String address, String clientName, String telephone){

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myservice.byethost33.com/insertOrder.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pizzaID", String.valueOf(pizzaID)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pizzaSize", String.valueOf(pizzaSize)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("income", String.valueOf(income)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clientName", clientName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telephone", telephone));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm new to android and php, but tell me if something isn't clear and I will try to explain.

Comment: Have you tried calling the php script outside android? What is the output? Do you get an error?

Comment: @DidierL no I didn't try, unfortunatelly I don't know how to do it...

Comment: You're not checking the return values of your calls to `mysql_*()` for errors so if something has gone wrong you won't know about it; you're using a deprecated API - use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO`; you aren't sanitising your inputs at all, so you are vulnerable to SQL injection; and any input that contains a single quote will break your `INSERT` queries.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Thanks I will keep your advices in mind for future projects. This is just a sample to see if this actually works.

Comment: @Tomek obviously it doesn't work or you wouldn't be here. He offers good debug advice that you should always try before making a question here.

Comment: @DaveS I understand, but at the moment I dont know how to do it.

Comment: You don't know what? how to check the return value? change mysql to mysqli? know how to google sanitize input? know how to google http debugging? You have to help yourself a little bit here man.

Comment: @DaveS I dont know how to check return value. Yes, I will use google.

Comment: You can get more information out of HttpResponse : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

Comment: In your `sales` table, for the `id` you have `NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`, and you're passing in `Null` in your insert statement.

Try specifying the columns, and let the `id` auto increment:

    `$SQLInsertSale = "INSERT INTO sales(order_date, status, user_id, pizza_id, pizza_size, income ) VALUES('{$time}', 'Waiting', '{$user}', '{$pizzaID}', '{$pizzaSize}', '{$income}');";`

Comment: Also, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php   and here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @DanielNugent I tried with your statement, but didn't help. I will look at it tomorrow. I need to get some sleep. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was simple php language issue and I wass passing wrong thing into `timestamp` field. I should be using `now()`.

```
$SQLInsertSale = "INSERT INTO sales VALUES(Null, now(), 'Waiting', '$user', '$pizzaID', '$pizzaSize', '$income');";
$someResult = mysql_query($SQLInsertSale);
```

**EDIT:**
As I learned little bit more about php, I started using PDO connection as you guys suggested to(with sanitizing and some error handling):

```
<?php
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=db4free.net; dbname=database; charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pizzaID = $_REQUEST['pizzaID'];
$pizzaSize = $_REQUEST['pizzaSize'];
$income = $_REQUEST['income'];
$address = $_REQUEST['address'];
$clientName = $_REQUEST['clientName'];
$telephone = $_REQUEST['telephone'];

try {
$insertSale = "INSERT INTO sales VALUES(Null, now(), 'Waiting', :user, :pizzaID, :pizzaSize, :income);";
$saleStatement = $connection->prepare($insertSale);
$saleStatement->execute(array(':user' => $user, ':pizzaID' => $pizzaID, 'pizzaSize' => $pizzaSize, 'income' => $income));

$lastID = $connection->lastInsertId();

$insertDelivery = 'INSERT INTO deliveries VALUES(:lastID, :address, :clientName, :telephone, 0.0);';
$deliveryStatement = $connection->prepare($insertDelivery);
$deliveryStatement->execute(array(':lastID' => $lastID, ':address' => $address,':clientName' => $clientName, ':telephone' => $telephone));

$connection = null;
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    print($ex->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I also change code in android class, because previous was deprecated. I included also some error handling(I get log message what happend after `insert` statement if it went wrong):

```
public static void sendData(String user, Integer pizzaID, Integer pizzaSize,  Double income,
                                                      String address, String clientName, String telephone){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.pvice.byethost33.com/insertOrder.php");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        data.append(URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8"));
        data.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("pizzaID", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pizzaID.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        data.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("pizzaSize", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pizzaSize.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        data.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("income", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(income.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        data.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("address", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8"));
        data.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("clientName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(clientName, "UTF-8"));
        data.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("telephone", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(telephone, "UTF-8"));

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(data.toString());
        writer.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("LOGG", line);
        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```